# Non existing xml tag handling in java code

Tags: java, xml

I have this issue which showed up in a very particular case. My XML is like

```
<xo:USAddress>
    <xo:Street>990 STANLEY CT</xo:Street>
    <xo:City>ERIE</xo:City>
    <xo:County>BOULDER</xo:County>
    <xo:State>COLORADO</xo:State>
    <xo:ZipCode>80516</xo:ZipCode>
  </xo:USAddress>
```

My code assumes that county information will always be there for US address but in certain cases like Virgin island, we don't get the county.
In my service class, I have below :

```
usAddress_Svc.setCounty(usAddress_PAS.getCounty().getStringValue());
```

In case , there is no county information in xml - how should i handle this condition. tried null check but that does not solve the purpose, please suggest.

Comment: Did you try `if (usAddress_PAS.getCounty().getStringValue().length() > 0) { usAddress_Svc.setCounty(usAddress_PAS.getCounty().getStringValue());} ` -- the county value may be non-null, but an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

You indeed would *not* typically get a null, as most XML parsers assume an empty string (which in Java is not the same as a null value). Try instead using `address.getCounty().isEmpty()` to determine whether or not the county is simply a blank value.

The only time you might have null is if the county field is not present, and the county value is not initialized. For cases like this, the best way to go might be to use a Java 8 Optional field (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html).

If the field is initialized to `Optional.empty()`, then you can use a simple expression to access its contents or return a default value, with this:

```
String county = address.getCounty().orElse("N/A");
```

This would return either the county, or the value "N/A". There are quite a few other useful methods.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Issue here is that 'm getting a null pointer in case county information is not available.

Comment: You might try retro-coding your county handling to use an `Optional` instead of a literal.